# Why is the classic ASP server-side include enclosed in a comment?

Tags: syntax, asp-classic, language-design

Why is the syntax for server-side inclusion `<!--#include file="suchandsuch"-->`?

Placing semantically meaningful content inside a comment seems awkward and misleading – indeed, the first time I saw this syntax, I assumed it was an include that had been "commented out". What was the reasoning behind designing the language to use this syntax, as opposed to alternatives like `<% #include file="suchandsuch" %>`?

(I'm aware that parsing that example alternative with simple substitution would render something like `<% <% vbscript_stuff %> html_stuff %>`, but it should be trivial to parse it a little more intelligently to avoid misusing HTML comments.)

Comment: I agree; it's just really strange to use a comment syntax for something that actually does something!  I have a long backgrouind in C, C++, and C# and coming to classic ASP really late in the game, it just seems "bogus".  I see the reasons below, and they seem valid, but imagine including a .h file in a line in C++ that began:  //

Comment: I have since learned that this sort of thing happens also in Oracle databases, where a comment can contain an "optimizer hint" that changes how a query is processed. I have no idea why semantically meaningful comments were ever considered a good idea, but apparently they are not a peculiarity of web code.

Comment: Good to know but just a horrendous idea by whoever designed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main reason is the server side processing in the case of server side includes is handled directly by IIS then passed off to the processing engine the content is related to.

So using the example in the question, if the syntax was;

```
<% #include file="suchandsuch" %>
```

then it's dealing direct with ASP processing syntax which means the SSI definition is no longer generic in it's approach.

As stated in the [MSDN Library documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525940(v=vs.90).aspx)

> *This directive can be used in an ASP page, STM page, INC page, or any page with a file name extension that is mapped to the SSI interpreter (Ssinc.dll) or to the ASP interpreter (Asp.dll). If you have IIS Manager installed, you can modify default application mappings and add new mappings.*

Also as the `<!-- -->` comment is processed server side it never reaches the client's browser so HTML semantics are unaffected.

---

**Useful Links**

- [IIS: Notes on Server-Side Includes (SSI) Syntax (KB 203064 Revisited)](http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited.aspx)

Comment: Ah, so it's processed before it even gets to the ASP parser. That would explain it. Thanks!

Comment: This may have some utility as described above, and thanks for the link and explanation.  Still, IMHO, a comment should never *do* anything, it should just be there.  Some other syntax should have been used ... this should be true across a wide variety of languages, platforms, etc.  Unfortunately, it isn't.  Whoever designed this was violating a really important principle.  For example in C++ // x++ would indicate commented out code; imagine if it still incremented x!

Comment: @JosephDoggie Technically though `<!-- # -->` is not an  HTML comment. Comments appear "client-side" where as an SSI is as the name suggests "server-side" and never shows to a client, it is only ever known to the IIS Server. In that respect they are not in my opinion comparable.

Comment: @ Lankymart, It's still known as comment syntax, many sites even call it this.  In any event, while its good to know that SSI is the correct name for it, and I appreciate that, it still is really really confusing.  My version of VS even highlights it in green, just like it was a comment.  This is the sort of thing that shouldn't be done.  I came to "classic ASP" as classic, when it wasn't classic, I didn't even do it.  Life's hard enough without syntax like that.... but I appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Server-side includes (and their "comment-style" format) are not confined to ASP/IIS -- it was used to enable the idea of server-side macros that would be processed by the server directly without rendering as text on the client.

Here's a helpful summary: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages/Server-Side_Includes

Comment: It's still really horrible syntax -- to use comments for something that actually does something!

Comment: @JosephDoggie You're not getting it, it's **not** a comment *(HTML)* it is an SSI directive *(`include` for example)* inside a HTML comments token *(`<!-- # -->`)*. Don't compare the two.