# Will an invalid file include in classic asp show up in my sourcecode?

Tags: asp-classic, include

If i include a File in classic ASP and it didnt work (maybe cause of an invalid directory), will it show the comment in the HTML Code?

Y or N is enough.

Comment: Would it have not been quicker to just test the hypothesis instead of asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will throw a runtime error not dissimilar to this;

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0126'

Include file not found

/yourfile.asp, line [insert number]

The include file '/includes/yourinclude.asp' was not found
```

Because the `#include` SSI *(Server Side Include)* directive is pre-processed by IIS before the response is returned by a server it will never appear on the client-side as a HTML comment.

If however you remove the hash (`#`) from `include` it is no longer a pre-processing instruction being ignored by IIS and treated as a normal HTML comment when rendered client-side.

---

### Useful Links

- [Why is the classic ASP server-side include enclosed in a comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25163326/692942) *(Bit more detail about how SSI is pre-processed).*